# ansible assign a fact value to a variable

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

I am new to ansible, I am writing a small playbook where it has to collect the fact value from the destination host and use that as a variable within the play. Can someone help me how to do that.

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: True
  become: true
  become_method: sudo
  become_user: root
  vars:
    BUILD_PATH: /opt/services/dev


  pre_tasks:
   - setup:
      filter: ansible_env
   - set_fact:
       tag: "{{ ansible_env.DATA_AGGREGATOR_ENV }}"
   - debug: var=ENV

  tasks:
    - name: Copy to Build to DATA
      shell: cp -pr {{ BUILD_PATH }} {{ ENV }}
```

Note: DATA_AGGREGATOR_ENV is environmental variable defined in all servers and the value vary from one server to other.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: You can directly use the var created by the setup task

Comment: as @papey said you can directly use facts in playbook, just "{{ ansible_env.DATA_AGG_ENV }}" of course "gather_facts" should be true, which is default

Comment: No, it didn't worked to me. I am getting this error "the field 'args' has an invalid value, which appears to include a variable that is undefined. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'DATA_AGGREGATOR_ENV'\n\n"

Answer (score 0):

You set the variable `tag`, but you use the variable `ENV`.

You have to set the `ENV` variable, if you want to use the `ENV` variable.

```
- set_fact:
    ENV: "{{ ansible_env.DATA_AGG_ENV }}"
```

Or you have to use the `tag` variable, if you have set the `tag` variable.

```
    shell: cp -pr {{ BUILD_PATH }} {{ tag }}
```

btw: the `filter` line lacks a space.

Comment: Thanks for your response I tried with the above changes and i am getting this error "FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "the field 'args' has an invalid value, which appears to include a variable that is undefined. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'DATA_AGGREGATOR_ENV'\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/u1/jenkins/workspace/Deploy_DAGG_Services/ecom-deploy/test.yml': line 15, column 6, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n       filter: ansible_env\n   - set_fact:\n     ^ here\n"}"

Comment: DATA_AGGREGATOR_ENV != DATA_AGG_ENV

Comment: oho sorry actual environmental variable is DATA_AGGREGATOR_ENV. Here  is the complete output. of ansible_env   "   "ansible_facts": {
        "ansible_env": {
            "DAGG_HOME": "/opt/services/dev/ecom-data-aggregator",
            "DATA_AGGREGATOR_ENV": "stage",
            "DPS_ENV": "stage",
            "PWD": "/home/ansible",
            "SHELL": "/bin/bash",
            "TERM": "xterm-256color",
            "USER": "ansible",
                "_": "/bin/sh"
        }
    },
    "changed": false
}"

Comment: The filter option filters only the first level subkey below ansible_facts. So how can i get the fact value below the first level